# Minecraft running at 2 fps; more than sufficient hardware specification, lag-o-meter maxed out during rendering pass and sporadic memory access errors

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, performance

I've been having very persistent issues on an old laptop of mine trying to get minecraft 1.12.2 to work. I have tried a lot of things and narrowed the issue down to what is almost certainly an engine / rendering / software issue that I can't seem to pinpoint.

Here are the specifics:

1. This computer is more than capable of running minecraft. 1ish GHZ processor, 6 GB of memory, Intel 4400. Everything I can find about these stats implies that it should work fine at 60 fps vanilla. Additionally, on my smaller, much slower, work-only mini-laptop with much worse stats, it runs better. I am very convinced it's not a hardware specification issue.
2. FPS is locked to 1-2. Nothing I change in settings fixes this. Optifine doesn't fix it, minimum everything doesn't fix it, nothing changes. In the lag-o-meter (which I can't provide a screenshot of now due to crashes on start), the graph isn't a graph but a solid red block which occupies the entirety of the left half of the screen, leading me to believe (according to documentation I've read about the meaning of the graph) that there is a serious rendering error occuring somewhere that is blocking everything.
3. Minecraft Version is 1.12.2 but I don't think that should matter. Running Java 8 Version 301, freshly installed. I've done everything: using MultiMC to reinstall minecraft, reinstalling Java, even completely reseting the PC itself (wiping the disk and reinstalling Windows). The problem persists. (EDIT: One thing I would note is that the laptop handles Bedrock edition without a hitch, but not Java edition. The possibility of CPU usage being a problem was brought up in the comments but the mini-laptop I used as a bench mark that runs Minecraft at an acceptable framerate has similar clock speed.)
4. To complicate the issue (and perhaps related as well), is the fact that there are seemingly random crashes on world-load due to a MEMORY_ACCESS_VIOLATION occurring in the Java runtime itself. This issue occurred before the system reset and after as well, although after the reset I was able to launch a world successfully once before the crashes started. They only appear to occur while loading a world.

I'm at a complete loss of what to do here to get Minecraft to work on this laptop. I have no idea what would cause this and what settings would persist through a full system reset to cause this issue to persist. I'm familiar with technical computer stuff but don't know much about Java or minecraft internals so I don't know where to proceed from here, and I'm just about out of energy to throw at the problem.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: What gfx card do you have? Minecraft will run OK even with very weak 3D accelerated card, but 1-2FPS is consistent with no 3D acceleration whatsoever, the gfx drivers using software (CPU) rendering, which is abysmally slow.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into graphics driver updates as well for your card. Also changing the java that runs Minecraft in your [Graphics Settings](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-set-per-app-graphical-performance-settings-in-windows-10) to high performance could also help.

Comment: I've been thinking about it being an issue with hardware acceleration not occurring. The graphics card is an integrated Intel 4400 HD, which is a stronger graphics card than the benchmark laptop I'm using (according to [this](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-UHD-Graphics-600-vs-Intel-HD-4400-Desktop-115-GHz/m407837vsm8064)), so the card specs itself is not an issue. I also attempted to update the drivers but they were already up to date. On a side note, does integrated graphics card count as hardware rendering? I know they render using the CPU but I figured it was faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory Access violation could be Minecraft having trouble with generating dump file after already silently crashing.

I would suggest looking into both BIOS updates (to help rule out issues with ram you could check if there is built-in health check tools provided by your laptop's manufacturer) and newest Intel graphics drivers - Intel has notoriously bad OpenGL support and it may be the reason behind the crashes/slow downs.

Comment: Thanks, I've been suspecting an issue with OpenGL, so I'm gonna check the website for updates instead of just relying on the device manager prompt. I've read a similar question with memory access violation where corrupted memory was an issue but the problem only occurs on minecraft specifically. I don't think it's an issue with Java either, since it runs fine in the menu.

Comment: This fixed the issue, but it took a very long time to eventually solve what could have been so simple if Intel's update management stuff wasn't so buggy. Only after I completely uninstalled my drivers and rebooted did I have the option to update. I searched the .dll given in the access violation error message and it led to old Stack Exchange threads that linked old minecraft pages that described memory  leaks in old Intel drivers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131371-Minecraft-Java-Edition-system-requirements-) the system requirements are at least an *Intel Core i3-3210 3.2 GHz*. Your integrated graphics is fine (minimum *Intel 4000*), but since Minecraft uses mostly CPU, you probably want to upgrade.

I'm not sure about why your other laptop was faster though, are you sure it's not running Bedrock Edition?

Comment: No, it's running Java edition. Not very good, but 20-30fps consistently is pretty good for a game like minecraft. The CPU usage is very much below maximum, so I didn't consider than an issue. EDIT: Actually it's a quad-core so I ought to double-check usage for one core, but I would be surprised if that was the culprit. I was under the impression nearly every computer could handle it. The laptop in question does handle Bedrock edition reasonable well though.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense, especially since (I believe) Minecraft only uses one core, which explains why it would run so well on a quad-core

Comment: I think I was being a bit unclear there, the mini-laptop I used as a performance benchmark has a processor with a similar clock speed, but it's dual core. The one I'm writing the question about that's having issues has a quad-core.

Comment: Oof, I don't know what to tell you then lol